# Overwriting _renderItem function in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm having trouble getting jQuery autocomplete to work when overriding the `_renderItem` function.  The following code works but when I uncomment the `_renderItem` it breaks it.  Everything else seems to be working correctly until I try to add the `_renderItem` function.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
      var availableTags = [
            <?php
            include ("./includes/open_database.php");
            $SQL = "CALL orders.get_inventory_2 ()";

            $q = mysqli_query($conn, $SQL);
            $i = 1;

            while ($qRow = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
            {
                echo '{ value: "' . $qRow["part_number"] . '", label: "' . $qRow["part_number"] . '", desc: "' . $qRow["description"] . '", file: "' . $qRow["filename"] . '", vendor: "' . $qRow["name"] . '" },';
            }

            include ("./includes/close_database.php");
            ?>
      ];

      function split(val) {
         return val.split(/;\s*/);
      }

      function extractLast(term) {
         return split(term).pop();
      }
      $("#part_numbers1")
         // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
         .on("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
               event.preventDefault();
            }
         }).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
               // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
               response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
            },
            focus: function() {
               // prevent value inserted on focus
               return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
               var terms = split(this.value);
               // remove the current input
               terms.pop();
               // add the selected item
               terms.push(ui.item.value);
               // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
               terms.push("");
               this.value = terms.join("; ");
               return false;
            }
         });.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
         return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
      };
   });
</script>
```

The `availableTags` variable ends up looking like this :

```
var availableTags = [{
   value: "",
   label: "",
   desc: "",
   file: "",
   vendor: ""
}, {
   value: "WES504",
   label: "WES504",
   desc: "",
   file: "",
   vendor: ""
}, {
   value: "WV057C",
   label: "WV057C",
   desc: "",
   file: "",
   vendor: ""
}];
```

Except with about 2000 values.

Comment: Please click `<>`, remove the PHP and create a [mcve]

Comment: I suspect there is a syntax error here: `});.data("ui-autocomplete")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues that I see here.

First, you have a syntax error:

```
        }
     });.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
     return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
  };
```

I believe you want this to be like so:

```
        }
     }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
     return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
  };
```

The extra `;` between `})` and `.data` causes JavaScript from reading the other command.

The second issue is the menu item itself:

```
     return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
```

You want the resulting HTML to be a List Item, containing a Div, containing the label. Not sure why you are using a Link.

You will want to use:

```
     return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<div><a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div></a>").appendTo(ul);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/d4hq5txc/